# Is there a way to fix this weird shading?

Tags: modeling, shaders

Ok So I'm trying to fix this shading so everything connects Perfectly without the weird triangle/ dark shading spots. (using auto Smooth)

things I've tried:
recalculating normal's, Converting Face's to triangle's and back to face's,
merging vertices' to make sure nothing is overlapping, converting all face's to triangles, using shade smooth.

And I still Cant fix it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you know how I can fix this please let me know.

here's the file

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe share this part of your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: do you mean the file?

Comment: select the edges in the cavity and either mark them sharp, split them, or bevel them.

Comment: Marking them sharp didnt fix it bevels change the shape and i cant split them bc i need it to manifold or (water tight)

Answer (score 4):

You could get rid of the triangles and revise the topology a bit, you'll have a good shading:

[image]